# Tooltip for Line Chart with Clip Path in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, linechart

[I have put together a D3 line chart](http://codepen.io/roydondsouza/pen/MwQzPG) and added threshold encoding using clip path / clipping. The only problem I am facing is I am not able to add tooltips to this chart. I want a tooltip when I hover anywhere in the chart and the corresponding y axis value on the chart shows up in the tooltip.

[image]

I have added threshold encoding using this [example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062844).

```
 var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return _config.xScale(d.vtc); })
    .y(function(d) { return _config.yScale(d.values); });

          svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-above")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("width", _config.width)
      .attr("height", _config.yScale(55));

  svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-below")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("y", _config.yScale(55))
      .attr("width", _config.width)
      .attr("height", _config.height - _config.yScale(55));


  svg.selectAll(".line")
      .data(["above", "below"])
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "line " + d; })
      .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d + ")"; })
      .datum(data)
      .attr("d", line);
```

I didn't know how to go about adding a tooltip for this particular chart as there is clip rectangle over the path and the path is broken down into above and below segment to give the colour effects.

[image]

Do we have a unified way to add a tooltip to normal path and this one? If yes I would like to know some sources/links I can look at.

Something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWp8VGQoRWHJaaxxLdGo?p=preview), but not that complicated (without any indicator on the line, just the tooltip)

[**My CODEPEN LINK**](http://codepen.io/roydondsouza/pen/MwQzPG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add mouseOver handler for the line and translate back the mouse y position to yAxis value using the .invert function of d3 linear scale. Now, you can dynamically add a tooltip text element and set the position, value to it

Here is the updated [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXaEpg)

NOTE: You still need to increase the capture area of the line. This can be done by adding a transparent stroke to the line.

```
  svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(["above", "below"])
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "line " + d; })
    .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d + ")"; })
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line)
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    var mousePos = d3.mouse(this);
    var yAxisValue = _config.yScale.invert(mousePos[1]);
    svg.selectAll(".tooltip").data([mousePos])
      .enter().append("text")
      .classed("tooltip", true)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0]})
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1]})
      .text(yAxisValue); 
   })
   .on("mouseout", function() {
      svg.selectAll(".tooltip").data([]).exit().remove();
   });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I will look into increasing the capture area, you have any pointers for that? Should I add a transparent stroke with a larger stroke width while appending the path itself?

Comment: Thanks. I would like one help. Check this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic and tell me how can I do this tooltip functionality when I move the mouse anywhere in the chart?